# Javascript getelementbyid doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

why does the following not work ?

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("page").style = "-webkit-filter: blur(5px);";
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page" style="" >some content</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you call it **after** the element is ready, using something like `window.onload` or just having the script physically on the page after the element...and set the appropriate property:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("page").style.webkitFilter = "blur(5px)";
};
```

The `style` property of an element is an object with properties you need to set. You shouldn't and can't just set the `style` property as a string. I get a `SyntaxError: invalid label` error when I try to.

I understand it was probably confusing for setting the special "-webkit-filter" style, but the "-webkit-" styles follow a convention in the `style` object - no leading "-", and replace other "-"s with camelCase.

At the same time, it's probably easier and more efficient (so you can add other styles) to toggle a `class`, instead of specifically setting a `style` property. So I would suggest using:

```
document.getElementById("page").className += " transformer";
```

And defining the CSS class:

```
.transformer {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

That way, if there are styles implemented in other specific browsers, it's easy to just add them here. Specifically, the use of vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably executing the script before the element was added to the page.

If your page is along the lines of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>...</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">some content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you'll need to wait for the document to be ready or the `onload` event before trying to access the `#page` element.